# Check all elements for an attribute and modify another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how my html looks,

```
<tr id="group-1-11">
<tr class="child-of-group-1-11 " selected-group="1" >
<tr id="group-1-12" class="child-of-group-1-11" parent-id="group-1-11"  selected-group="1">
<tr class="child-of-group-1-12" parent-id="group-1-12"  selected-group="1">
<tr class="child-of-group-1-12" parent-id="group-1-12"  selected-group="1">
<tr class="child-of-group-1-11" selected-group="1" >
<tr id="group-1-85" class="child-of-group-1-11" parent-id="group-1-11" >
<tr class="child-of-group-1-85" selected-group="1" style="display: none;">
<tr id="group-1-355" class="child-of-group-1-85" parent-id="group-1-85" selected-group="1">
<tr id="group-1-2" class="child-of-group-1-11  parent " parent-id="group-1-11">
```

now what is my problem is that I need to check if the element with class child-of-id have property selected-group="1" and if all of the child-of-id have the property then add new property(checked,true) to element with that particular id.

```
// I have an array of ids
// var uniqueParentArray = ['group-1-11', 'group-1-12', 'group-1-85',...];
$.each(uniqueParentArray, function(index, parentId) {
            var allSelected = $('.child-of-'+parentId).each(function(){
                var selectedGroup = $(this).attr('selected-group');
                if(selectedGroup != '1')
                    return false;
                return true;
            });
            if(allSelected) {
                $('#'+parentId).attr("checked", true);
            }
      });
```

That means by the end my result should be something like:

```
 <tr id="group-1-12" class="child-of-group-1-11" parent-id="group-1-11"  selected-group="1" checked="true">
 <tr id="group-1-85" class="child-of-group-1-11" parent-id="group-1-11" checked="true">
```

but element with `id = "group-1-11"` **should not** have that attribute `checked = "true"`

I hope the context was clear. I probably have a bug in the script, hence result output is not as expected. Please help me fix the bug, I was expecting `allSelected` to be boolean but I probably am not very familiary with the methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.each()` does not function as you want it to. You need to create a variable before your call to `.each()`, and then modify the variable if you encounter the condition you're looking for.

```
$.each(uniqueParentArray, function(index, parentId) {
    var allSelected = true;
    $('.child-of-'+parentId).each(function(){
        var selectedGroup = $(this).attr('selected-group');
        if(selectedGroup != '1') {
            allSelected = false;
        }
    });
    if(allSelected) {
        $('#'+parentId).attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

This code will loop through all `.child-of-(parentID)` elements. If any of them do not have `selected-group="1"`, then `allSelected` will be false when the loop completes.

On a more general note, I would recommend using `data-` attributes for non-standard HTML attributes. This way your markup remains valid.

Comment: Hmm!! why didn't I think about it, Thank you @jackwanders. but this does call for unnecessary loop, thank you once again but I think I'll wait for other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

`return true` in jQuery `.each` is the same thing as `continue;` in a for loop. `return false` is the equivalent of `break;`. None of these will be used as return values for the iteration, and passed to `allSelected`. You might be looking at something like `.filter` rather than `.each`, which is a reduce, where returning false would mean that the element is excluded from the list.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
$('#' + uniqueParentArray.join(', #')).attr('checked', function() {
   return $('.child-of-' + $(this).attr('id')).filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('selected-group') != '1';
   }).length == 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$.each(uniqueParentArray, function(index, parentId) {
    // retrieve not selected elements for the given parent
    var notSelectedElements = $('.child-of-'+parentId+'[selected-group!="1"]');
    // if all elements are selected
    if(notSelectedElements.length === 0) {
         $('#'+parentId).attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```